# Ruby on Rails - Could not find matching strategy for :google_oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I have got

```
gem 'omniauth-google_oauth2'
```

in my  Gemfile. Did bundle install after that as well.  It errors out saying,

> ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/omniauth-1.0.2/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:33:in
>   `rescue in provider': Could not find matching strategy for
>   :google_oauth2. You may need to install an additional gem (such as
>   omniauth-google_oauth2). (LoadError)

What am I missing? Any ideas please.

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
```

Change the last underscore to a hyphen.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is caused by how OmniAuth camelizes the provider names:

`OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(:google_oauth2.to_s)` => `GoogleOAuth2`

However the provider is actually `GoogleOauth2` - fully qualified - `OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleOauth2`

So the solution is to use the fully qualified class:
`OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleOauth2`

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleOauth2, ENV["KEY"], ENV["SECRET"]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Ben W's solution made the server start-able but screws up how I was doing routes. I used this in `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`

```
:google_oauth2, "[KEY]", "[SECRET]"
```

My google auth path is then `/auth/google_oauth2`